# Excel document opens in IE 64, not in IE 32

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, microsoft-excel, internet-explorer-8

Whenever I click on a hyperlink to a scrip that outputs an Excel 8 document, I get a prompt from IE to open the file or save-as.  If I click open in IE 32 bit, the document opens in Excel (which is what I want).  If I click open in the 64 bit version of IE, the document opens in the browser.

How can I make both versions of IE open in Excel?  I am using IE8 on Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

In IE8.64, go to tools/internet options/security/custom level and check if "Automatic prompting for file downloads" is disabled.  Enable it and try again.